# Accessing a onedrive excel file of a personal user from any cloud service like Vercel, Cloudflare using NodeJS

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Is it possible to access a onedrive file from a backend service (no user UI or authentication) like a cron job?

The approach I am trying out is:

1. Create a daemon user or whatever it is called in one-drive (or office365)
2. Ask user to share file with this daemon user
3. In some way (that is my question) use the daemon user's credentials (name/pw or token etc) to access the file

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to download the file or create a sharing link for the file?

Comment: I wish to read the contents of the file. Thanks @user2250152